# Shopify API Updating Inventory Levels Not Working

Tags: shopify

I am trying to update my inventory levels using the Shopify API. I am trying to get it to work using Postman.

[image]

[image]

I am getting this as a response

```
<html>
<body>
    <noscript>
    <a href="REDACTED">Continue</a>
    </noscript>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "REDACTED";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API call is running into issues at API Authentication step. This problem arise, when you are sending cookies with POST request.

From the [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/using-postman),

> Shopify prevents HTTP Basic Auth POST requests that have cookies,
>   which can cause POST calls to fail. If your POST call fails, then you
>   should try clearing your cookies.

To clear the cookies, use the Cookie manager in Postman app that can be accessed using **Cookies** button located below the Send and Save buttons.